# Capture data from various places and get it insto one named group

Tags: regex, splunk, capturing-group, regex-group

I have some data I like to analyze using Splunk.  Data is in the follwoing format.

```
18.02.2016 13:55:55 01D4 PACKET  014D4198 UDP Snd 10.10.10.148    9e8b R Q [8081   DR  NOERROR] A     (5)rover(4)ebay(3)com(0)
18.02.2016 13:55:27 01C4 PACKET  014E1E38 UDP Rcv 10.10.10.160    fa2b   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A     (2)ib(5)adnxs(3)com(0)
```

I need various part inn to named group using regex.

Example to get the IP, I have the folloing:

```
(Snd|Rcv)\s(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s
```

That gives:

```
ip 10.10.10.148
ip 10.10.10.160
```

But how to get the URL to one named group like this:

```
url rover.ebay.com
url ib.adnxs.com
```

I thought using  **Non-Capturing Groups** within a named Capturing Groups, but that is clearly not correct:

```
\(\d+\)(?<url>\w+(?:\(\d+\))\w+(?:\(\d+\))\w+(?:\(\d+\)))
```

Not working.

PS url may not be in vaious length, so that should be handled as well.

```
(2)ib(5)adnxs(3)com(2)br(0)
```

Comment: I guess you need to replace: [`\s\(\d+\)([^()]+)\(\d+\)([^()]+)\(\d+\)([^()]+)\(\d+\)$` --> `url $1.$2.$3`](https://regex101.com/r/tT5xP2/1). Or - if their number is varied, use [`\s\(\d+\)\K(?:[^()\n]+\(\d+\))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/tT5xP2/3) to match the substrings, and then replace `\(\d+\)` with `.`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This will the be locked to 3 part. I am not sure how to do it with multiple lines as well.  Need it one line.